# Как можно подключить мою отправку сообщений от к PHP-файлу, чтобы все сообщения, введенные в форму, отправлялись непосредственно на мой адрес Gmail?

Tags: php, html, form, sendmessage

### Contact us We are open to talk. We work for you. Let us talk!

```
                          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter full name" name="name" required="">
                
                               <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email address" name="email" required="">

                               <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Tell us about your message" name="message" required=""></textarea>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                               <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="send message" value="Send Message">
                          </div>

                     </form>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой способ - встроенная в PHP функция [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php)

Более современный способ - использование сервисов почтовой рассылки, рекомендую [mailchimp](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-php)

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию!